# Access to built-in icons for Menu Items?

Tags: google-mirror-api

I know you can use `iconUrl` to customize icon for custom menu items but is there a way to access built-in icons such as checkbox that you see during confirmation for `REPLY`?

Answer (score 1):

No.  There's currently no way override this part of the interface, but it is something that could potentially be added to the API.

You may want to file an enhancement request in the Glass API [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/list). IF you do, please include your intended use case.

Comment: Please add it! I would love to see this feature as well.

Comment: Agreed. It would help in creating a consistent UI experience.